# How estimator of tensorflow load specific steps of model instead of latest one?

Tags: tensorflow

We can save many checkpoints of model using Estimator and `RunConfig`.

`classifier` eval will use the latest step `200` by default,
 **can I load `ckpt-1`**?

```
my_checkpointing_config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(
    save_checkpoints_secs = 20*60,  # Save checkpoints every 20 minutes.
    keep_checkpoint_max = 10,       # Retain the 10 most recent checkpoints.
)
classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
    feature_columns=my_feature_columns,
    hidden_units=[10, 10],
    n_classes=3,
    model_dir='models/iris',
    config=my_checkpointing_config)



$ ls -1 models/iris
checkpoint
events.out.tfevents.timestamp.hostname
graph.pbtxt
model.ckpt-1.data-00000-of-00001
model.ckpt-1.index
model.ckpt-1.meta
model.ckpt-200.data-00000-of-00001
model.ckpt-200.index
model.ckpt-200.meta
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both `tf.estimator.Estimator.evaluate` and `tf.estimator.Estimator.predict` have a `checkpoint_path` argument. You should be able to supply the path to `model.ckpt-1` here to use this checkpoint for evaluation.

Note that this argument was added in a fairly recent TF update (might be 1.7 or 1.8, not quire sure) so if you are using an outdated version you might not have this argument available. There is a hacky alternative: In the `model_dir` there should be a file called `checkpoint`. The first line of this file should be

```
model_checkpoint_path: "model.ckpt-xxxxxx"
```

where `xxxxxx` is the number of steps for the latest checkpoint (200 in your case). You can manually change this line to whatever checkpoint you want the `Estimator` to load. However you will probably want to change it back afterwards or you might run into issues if you ever want to continue training the model.

Comment: in the recently tensorflow 1.12, the full filepath is needed. like `${OUTPUT_DIR}/model.ckpt-65000`